# Android AVD SQLite Files - Browse?

Tags: android, file, android-virtual-device

How can I browse and copy out the files in my Android AVD? I wish to view the contents of the Sqlite file the app modifies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the File Manager in DDMS (either the standalone program or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse). Your SQLite databases should be in:

```
/data/data/your.package.here/databases/
```

where `your.package.here` is whatever package name you gave your application in the manifest.